# Elderly Father Wishes to have YouTUBE GUI from AppleTV 2

Tags: appletv, youtube

This is a follow up to [Workaround for YouTube to appear in Apple TV](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/184694/workaround-for-youtube-to-appear-in-apple-tv)

I got my father AppleTV 3rd generation and he HATES the YouTUBE User Interface.

He says if YouTUBE API for old Apple TV (we purchased in 2012) is 100, the new YouTUBE UI is 5.

He is even willing to pay $20/month to use the old UI if Apple is offering it.

He is so frustrated and angry at this. He's not computer literate at all, and YouTUBE from old AppleTV was the best he could do.

I was thinking of Google Chrome, but I'd like to see a demo of it before purchasing it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If he's willing to spend that amount of money then he might as well consider getting the Chromecast. The Chromecast doesn't necessarily work on it's own in the sense that it could work off nothing but a remote but it has an amazingly solid playlist queue that anyone in the house can just sort of throw videos into.

If it's just a YouTube experience alone, I can say from experience that the Chromecast to this day is the best YouTube has to offer in terms of user experience.

Comment: BTW an "API" is an Application Programming Interface. Something that only programmers see and work with. I assume you mean he hates the User Interface?

Comment: @SteveChambers Maybe the OP means "UI"?

Comment: @SteveChambers Yes, the User Interface. I updated the question.